# 401 unauthorised while creating google storage bucket using Micronaut java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, micronaut, micronautgcp

Micronaut documentation support for google cloud https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-gcp/2.0.x/guide/

Setting up GCP Support

```
implementation("io.micronaut.gcp:micronaut-gcp-common:2.0.2")
```

Setting the credential in `application.yml`

```
gcp:
  credentials:
    location: classpath:googleStorageKey.json
```

`googleStorageKey.json` is located on the same directory as `application.yml` file

The google service account file contains the below data

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "fetebird",
  "private_key_id": "cf93ffffffjjhjyyuyu144842f20dc055763aa665",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEv--REDACTED--4XOs=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "fetebirdstorage@fetebird.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "106425305070351254286",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/fetebirdstorage%40fetebird.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Here is the code I used to create the bucket with options

```
public Observable<Void> createBucketWithStorageClassAndLocation() {
        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(googleUploadObjectConfiguration.projectId()).build().getService();
        StorageClass storageClass = StorageClass.COLDLINE;
        try {
            Bucket bucket =
                    storage.create(
                            BucketInfo.newBuilder(googleUploadObjectConfiguration.bucketName())
                                    .setStorageClass(storageClass)
                                    .setLocation(googleUploadObjectConfiguration.locationName())
                                    .build());
            LOG.info(String.format("Created bucket %s in %s with storage class %s", bucket.getName(), bucket.getLocation(), bucket.getStorageClass()));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return Observable.empty();
    }
```

Reference - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-create-bucket-clss-location

Exception

```
401 Unauthorized
POST https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=fetebird&projection=full
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Inside the `Storage.options` the credentials are null, that is the reason I am getting 401. It should pick the credential from the application.yml file location.

Where I am making mistake?

Followed the instruction from here https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically

After exposing this command

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/my-key.json"
```

Still not able to authenticate, I think I am missing something.

Service account permission
[image]

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding --member=serviceAccount:fetebird-storage@fetebird.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/storage.admin fetebird
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add this line to check if you env var is correctly injected in the runtime context: `System.out.println(System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"));`

Comment: In addition, what are the permission of the service account? And what is the mode of the bucket Fine Grained or Uniform?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the environment variable is null, permission to the service account is storage admin

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - there is another question related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66452523/the-application-default-credentials-are-not-available-with-environment-variable can you please have a look

Comment: how do you run your code? In a terminal or with your IDE (intelliJ?)?

Comment: With IDE Intellj

Comment: I answered with screenshot Let me know if it works (I can't paste screenshot in comment!)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere that didn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to configure correctly your IDE runtime environment

- Edit your runtime config
  [image]
- Then add your environment variable in the dedicated field

[image]

- And validate.

Try again and let me know!

Comment: I do get now the file from this code System.out.println(System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")); but the credentials are still null in the storage and getting 401

Comment: From the gcp doc Environment variable only applies to your current shell session, so if you open a new session, set the variable again, what does this mean with IDE ?

Comment: with gcloud auth application-default login command works but this is not a recommended way

Comment: `gcloud auth application-default login` is, IMO, a most recommend way than having a service account key file on your side! Only my opinion ;)

Comment: If you have a 401, it's not because your haven't credential, but because your credential isn't valid or authorized. Can you try to perform a call with service account impersonation? `gsutil -i <service account email> ls`

Comment: After running  gsutil -i  fetebird-storage@fetebird.iam.gserviceaccount.com ls I can see the service account name, updated the permission screenshot in the question, however, still getting 401

Comment: Ok, so, it's consistent: Your service account can't access to the bucket. What are the role of the service account and on which resources? Is the bucket in the same project?

Comment: Yes the bucket should create in the same project as I am passing the projected in the option section of the Storage, I have updated the roles screenshot in the question above, the code is creating a bucket in the GCS. So while creating a bucket using the java library I am getting 401 exception

Comment: In your screenshot, the service account doesn't have storage admin role. If it's the case, it's the root cause I guess

Comment: please have a look again, added a new screen-shot with admin role

Comment: Not "service account admin", but "storage admin". Use this command to grant it `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding --member=serviceAccount:fetebirdstorage@fetebird.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/storage.admin fetebird`

Comment: What permission do I need to provide for project instance access. I have assigned security admin permission But getting an error as ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding) User [fetebird-storage@fetebird.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission to access projects instance [fetebird:getIamPolicy] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission

Comment: I have given owner permission as well and I think storage admin is the owner

Comment: Ok, you haven't the permission to grant role because you are connected, in the CLI, with the service account and not with your user account. You can open a cloud shell and paste the command in it; Or simply go to the IAM page, and add the storage.admin role to the service account email.

Comment: I have run the command on the cloud shell, and attached the screen shot in the question, but still the same issue

Comment: Did you wait 2 minutes? Cloud Storage permission sometime take time to be enforced...

Comment: Yes,  I tried after 1 hour as well same thing

Comment: I don't really no. You have exhausted my ideas! You can try the policy troubleshooter to try to understand the issue: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/troubleshooting-access

Comment: After running that command from the cloud shell, I still don't see storage admin role in the permission tab. I believe owner is the storage admin role

Comment: Keep in mind that you allow permission on resources. Allow permission on Project resource or on Bucket resource for example. Service Account is an hybrid strange stuff that is a ressource and an account (yes you can grant permission to a service account on itself!!). In your case, you want to grant a permission on the project resource to create a bucket on it. You don't have permission tab on a project, the project resource level is represented by the IAM page. Take care of what you do, and think wisely!

Comment: With the same permission the command  gcloud auth application-default login works, its only not working with the service account from local machine

Answer (score 1):

Anyone struggling with this issue maybe this is helpful, the path should be in without the quotation mark. If you are on MAC machine, copy the path using the option key on keyboard and paste it here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inject the GoogleCredentials and set it on the storage object

Comment: How about the environment variable, I set the environment variable on my local machine and export the command, it should pick up that .json file?

Comment: I have no idea, that is specific to GCP. The micronaut integration creates a credentials object you can use

Answer (score 0):

Community Wiki made to add what was discussed in the comments to @GuillaumeBlaqueire's answer to a proper and separate answer.

If you have a status 401, it's not because you haven't credentials, but because your credential isn't valid or authorized. This was proved by your test using the `gsutil -i <service account email> ls` command.

So what you need to do in order to fix this issue is to add the role, described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles), that best fits the permissions necessary to your service account. Which would be the `Storage Admin` Role.

Comment: Thanks for the input, however, I do already have Storage Admin permission as shown in the screenshot above, and applying all the comments provided by @GuillaumeBlaqueire's still I am facing a 401 exceptions.However, with the gcloud auth application-default login command I am able to create the bucket