# The Application Default Credentials are not available with environment variable setup in mac Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, micronaut

```
 The Application Default Credentials are not available.
 They are available if running in Google Compute Engine.
 Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials
```

Keep getting the above error instead I have set the environment variable on my local machine with the below command

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/macbook/Downloads/fetebird-2b6fa8261292.json"
```

If I check the path for the environment variable with the below command on terminal it does show the path of the variable

```
echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

[image]

On Micronaut application I am trying to create a storage bucket during the startup

```
@Singleton
public class StartUp implements ApplicationEventListener<StartupEvent> {
    private final GoogleCloudStorageService googleCloudStorageService;

    public StartUp(GoogleCloudStorageService googleCloudStorageService) {
        this.googleCloudStorageService = googleCloudStorageService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(StartupEvent event) {
        try {
            this.googleCloudStorageService.createBucketWithStorageClassAndLocation().subscribe();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On the service

```
@Singleton
public record GoogleCloudStorageService(GoogleCloudStorageConfiguration googleUploadObjectConfiguration, GoogleCredentialsConfiguration googleCredentialsConfiguration) {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoogleCloudStorageService.class);

    public Observable<Void> createBucketWithStorageClassAndLocation() throws IOException {
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(); // fromStream(new FileInputStream(googleCredentialsConfiguration.getLocation()));
        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).setProjectId(googleUploadObjectConfiguration.projectId()).build().getService();
        StorageClass storageClass = StorageClass.COLDLINE;
        try {
            Bucket bucket =
                    storage.create(
                            BucketInfo.newBuilder(googleUploadObjectConfiguration.bucketName())
                                    .setStorageClass(storageClass)
                                    .setLocation(googleUploadObjectConfiguration.locationName())
                                    .build());
            LOG.info(String.format("Created bucket %s in %s with storage class %s", bucket.getName(), bucket.getLocation(), bucket.getStorageClass()));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return Observable.empty();
    }
}
```

The environment variable is NULL while running the application

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"))
```

The `GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();` causing an exception as

```
java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:134)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:120)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:92)
    at fete.bird.service.gcp.GoogleCloudStorageService.createBucketWithStorageClassAndLocation(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:24)
    at fete.bird.core.StartUp.onApplicationEvent(StartUp.java:24)
    at fete.bird.core.StartUp.onApplicationEvent(StartUp.java:11)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.notifyEventListeners(DefaultBeanContext.java:1307)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.publishEvent(DefaultBeanContext.java:1292)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:248)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:166)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:71)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:311)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:297)
    at fete.bird.ServiceApplication.main(ServiceApplication.java:8)
```

Is it on `StartupEvent` the micronaut doesn't access the environment variable?

Answer (score 3):

Well I was missing the below instruction

**Local development/testing**

If running locally for development/testing, you can use the `Google Cloud SDK`. Create Application Default Credentials with `gcloud auth application-default login`, and then google-cloud will automatically detect such credentials.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java

However, this solution is not perfect, since it is using the OAuth authentication and getting the warning as `Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts.`